# How to handle dynamic ID in HTML

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have to click on the button which has `id`. But this `id` is generated dynamically. And find `By.className()` is not doing anything.

The HTML code for the button:

```
<td class="x-btn-mc">
    <em class="" unselectable="on">
        <button id="cq-gen372" class=" x-btn-text" type="button">OK</button>
    </em>
</td>
```

How to select the button and click on it in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`By.className()` really was bugged in IE and some older Selenium versions. I didn't know it is still the case. Anyway! You can search by a lot of things, not just id:

You can try `By.xpath("//button[text()='OK']");` if it is the only (or the first) OK button on page.

For more xpaths, see [XPath v1.0 on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) and [XPath v2.0 on w3.org - only for some new browsers!](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/).

Or you can go with css selectors - [The w3 again](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_selector#Syntax).

Comment: Thanks u Slanec. But this is not helping me.. the OK button is out of the frame                                                       driver.switchTo().frame("cq-gen379");
selenium.type("id=CQrte","thx");                                    By.xpath("//button[text()='OK']").click(); my code is woking fine up to type. But since i don't know how to come out the frame its failing. the swicthTo.defaultContent() taking me to main window,and this is popup i-frame. Please help me...

Comment: The switchTo frame seems to be ok. But you can't mix `selenium` and `driver` commands together - or you can, but the `switchTo()` only works for `driver`, `selenium` still thinks you're in the main window. For `selenium`, you would need to use `selectFrame()`.
Or just stick to `driver` and get rid of `selenium`:

`driver.switchTo().frame("cq-gen379");
driver.findElement(By.id("CQrte")).sendKeys("thx");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='OK']").click());`

Comment: NO LUCK :(. How to get out of the {frame.driver.switchTo().frame("cq-gen379")} As OK button is out of the iframe.

Comment: Oh. Look at [The Documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#frame%28int%29). You can switch to any frame depending on their index :). And in the end, return to `switchTo.defaultContent();`

Answer (score 1):

You can go with below options

```
  //button[text()='OK']    
  xpath=//button[contains(., 'OK')]
  //button[contains(@class, 'x-btn-text')]
```

Comment: tnx Rohti but no luck, Could u please see my comments to Slanec above, I wonder if u can help me on this...

Comment: as Slanes said, you first go with selectframe() then click on particular element